# Grayscale Indexed8 QImage tilted

Tags: arrays, grayscale, qimage

I am a little desperate. I need to visualize a matrix (which in this case is a simple int matrix using the armadillo library, holding values between 0 and 240) within a QT App.

However, using the following short procedure within a class, I always get a tilted image.

First, here my code

```
QImage matImage::matToIMage(const arma::imat &theMatrix)
{
    const auto numRows(theMatrix.n_rows);
    const auto numCols(theMatrix.n_cols);

    uchar *datap = new uchar[numCols*numRows];
    //int *datai = new int[numCols*numRows];

    int idx(0);
    for (auto y = 0; y < numRows; ++y)
    {
        for (auto x=0; x < numCols; ++x)
        {
            datap[idx] = static_cast<char>(theMatrix(y, x));
            //datai[idx] = theMatrix(y, x);
            ++idx;
        }
    }

    QVector<QRgb> grayscale;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
    {
        grayscale.append( qRgb(i, i, i) );
    }

    QImage image(datap, numCols, numRows, QImage::Format_Indexed8);
    image.setColorTable(grayscale);

    return image;
}
```

and here the resulting image of a 60x82 matrix, which has two block submatrices (it really has, the data is correct..)

[image]

Why is the image tilted? It looks like the column amount isn't correct but I just can't see any error.

Looking forward to getting help,

thanks a lot,
G.

P.S.: The image, when enlarged, alltogether has three different blocks of graylevels. However they are difficult to see. The tilt can be seen already looking at the brightest color only.

EDIT: When switching from Indexed8 to RGB32 Imageformat and using setPixel, all works just fine. However, I prefer 8but images for my purposes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the rows are not aligned... QImage documentation says image data must be 32-bit aligned and each individual row must also be 32-bit aligned.

Comment: That seems a very likely reason, thanks for the reply -- even though some time has passed meanwhile!